# MongoDB update document with _id query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using nodejs and the native mongo driver to update document in my collection.
I can't query for the _id in my update statement.

```
  db.users.update({
       _id: user._id
   }, {
       $set: {
           userName: user.userName,
           email: user.email,
           icon: user.icon,
           role: user.role
       }
   }, {
       multi: false
   }, next);
```

what is the right way of doing it?

Comment: Where is the "user" object coming from? It also might help to show what the document you are trying to update looks like. Anything by "_id" is never "multi" since that is the primary key.

Comment: the user in a parameter of the function that wraps this update statement.
it has an _id.
I think the problem is because user._id is a string and this field in the database is ObjectId. I think I need a way to convert this string to ObjectId but I can't find it in the documentation

Comment: That is the problem. ObjectId is a function that you import with the `require("mongodb").ObjectId`